# Getting different binary for the same Solidity source code compiling with solc and Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, solc, compiler, compilation

I'm noticing a difference in the binary generated using the same solc compiler in local and with Remix.

Here's the source code:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;
contract HelloWorld {}
```

I compiled it in local using `solc 0.8.20+commit.a1b79de6.Darwin.appleclang` with the following command: `solc --bin --evm-version=shanghai src/HelloWorld.sol`

Then I compiled it using remix:

[image]

Using solc in local I get:
`6080604052348015600e575f80fd5b50603e80601a5f395ff3fe60806040525f80fdfea26469706673582212207b2707958b214a2fbb3ee97873fd5450b38f093d306ca27f3ab234659b8a6f8064736f6c63430008140033`

Using Remix:
`6080604052348015600e575f80fd5b50603e80601a5f395ff3fe60806040525f80fdfea2646970667358221220d6df573e47185fc28b4a57d786409da70c81ef5acd34160533da68ef8405873c64736f6c63430008140033`

At first sight the outputs look identical but they are different. I used the same compiler version, same evm version and no optimization, so I wonder what else could cause this difference?

Comment: While you've mentioned using the same compiler version and EVM version, differences in the compilation environment can still exist. For example, Remix might use a different operating system or underlying dependencies compared to your local environment, which could affect the compilation process.

Comment: I can see this part of the bytecode is same, even in my case when I compiled:

`6080604052348015600e575f80fd5b50603e80601a5f395ff3fe60806040525f80fdfea2646970667358221220.............64736f6c63430008140033`